# Как перенести данные из одного вектора в другой?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, перемещение

Есть `std::vector<char> fromBlock` с 10^9  элементов.
И есть пустой `std::vector<char> toBlock`

Нужно максимально быстро перенести данные `fromBlock` в `toBlock`, при этом очистить `fromBlock`.
Это осложнено тем, что данную операцию нужно проивести в функции, в которой есть лишь указатель на `fromBlock`, а также внутри функции живет `toBlock` (в ней он создается и в ней разрушается).

Пример:

```
int main(){
    std::vector<char> fromBlock;
    ... // Здесь заполняем fromBlock
    сonvert(&fromBlock);
}

void convert(std::vector<char>* fromBlock){
    std::vector<char> toBlock;
    ...// Здесь как-то и должно произвестись переменщение
}
```

Собственно, как перенести данные из одного вектора в другой?

P.S.
Читал про

```
std::move
```

, но особо не понял, как он работает и есть ли алтернатива.

Comment: `std::swap(*fromBlock, toBlock)`?

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл как идея - норм. Но вообще - вы тогда выполняете лишнее обратное действие std::move из toBlock в fromBlock. Я же уточнил, что нужно максимально быстро перемещать, в этом и основной вопрос.

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл подозреваю, что максимально быстро можно с помощью std::move, но я несовсем понял - как он работает с указателями

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG а вы точно понимаете что происходит при `std::swap(*fromBlock, toBlock)`?

Comment: Куда ж ещё быстрее? Сложность константная, под капотом просто меняет указатели на буферы с данными, а сами данные не копирует.

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл, сорри, неправильно понял смысл swap - видно уже перегрелся)
Спасибо - думаю, что это и есть ответ на мой вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо, **@ДжонниКэтсвилл**

Можно использовать `std::swap` - работает за константу

Можно также использовать `std::move` - тоже работает за константу

Разница вот в чем:

> **swap** 
> 1) поменять данные местами
>
> **move** 
> 1) Освободить ресурсы в конечном векторе
>  2) Присвоить данные 
> 3) Обнулить вектор, данные из которого переместили

Код, чтобы посмотреть разницу в работе
https://ideone.com/OmEjbl